# jquery cloning new elements and adding variable to name

Tags: jquery, clone

Hi I have this jQuery Function to duplicate form fields. Now I need to process them with PHP and my problem is that the cloned elements have the same input name.

I would like to add and variabel on the end of the name like _1 _2 _3 and so on. Also it would be great to put in a hidden field the amount of cloned elements to process them in a loop.

I'm really not good in jQuery and need it pretty quick otherwise I would start reading documentary about it and do it myself.

Maybe u guys can help me out. Would appriciate it a lot :)

There is the jQuery Part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

    newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

    $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');

    if (newNum == 10)// Max
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
});

$('#btnDel').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

    $('#input' + num).remove();
    $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled','');

    if (num-1 == 1)
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
});

$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

});

And here the HTML

```
<div id="input1" class="clonedInput">
<!-- Elements to clone -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="">Firmenname</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge {validate:{required:true}}" rel="popover" data-content="Der Firmenname ist ein wichtiger Hinweis." data-original-title="Hilfe" id="firma" name="firma">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="">Branche</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="branche">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="">Anschrift</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="anschrift">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="">Ansprechpartner</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="ansprechpartner">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="">Tel.</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge">
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END Elements to clone -->    
</div>
```

Comment: Sure and I'dont understand jQuery, it is a private project and I can't afford to hire somone to do it for me. Most of my code I write myself I'm just asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your input names should all be `name[]` rather than `name_1`, `name_2`, etc. PHP recognizes this name format, and makes `$_POST['name']` an array, with an element for each of the inputs with that name.

You still need to give elements unique IDs. But perhaps your cloned inputs don't need IDs at all, so you can avoid this problem entirely.

You might also want to look at the jquery-dynamic-form plugin. However, I just checked and it doesn't address this problem (in fact, the demo where the + and - buttons are embedded in each row has duplicate IDs, so it's not a valid DOM).

BTW, you don't need to use `new Number`.  Just write:

```
var newNum = num+1;
```

Comment: thank you, I'll check that out. I'm already working with name[] in the backend to add this forms :). I will try it that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To make a unique id, just keep a counter that starts at 0 and increments by 1 every time you make a new clone. Then concatenate this counter to your name field.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, I'm still not there to test but I'll try and let you know :)